# How to set up Kafka-connector to use custom transform in Debezium?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm new to Kafka and I can't figure out how to use "transforms.router.type" to make it work with my Debezium setup.
So I made special event transformation java class and prepeared configuration for it to deploy to container which looks like this:

curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d

```
{
  "name": "task-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "slot.name" : "task_engine_saga",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "tasks",
    "schema.whitelist": "public",
    "table.whitelist" : "public.task",
    "tombstones.on.delete" : "false",
    "transforms" : "router",
    "transforms.router.type" : "com.task.connect.TaskEventRouter"
  }
}
```

And the response says that this config can't be found.

```
CREATE kafka connector task-connector....
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1091  100   516  100   575   8322   9274 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17596{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 3 error(s):\nInvalid value com.task.connect.TaskEventRouter for configuration transforms.router.type: Class com.task.connect.TaskEventRouter could not be found.\nInvalid value null for configuration transforms.router.type: Not a Transformation\nA value is required\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

Then I copied to container /connect directory my host folder with jar file in which I have my java class with event transformation logic, but it didn't help too. Could someone please help me and tell what should I do to make this custom transforms.router.type work with my Debezium set up?

My containers docker-compose set up:

```
version: '3'
services:
    pgadmin:
        container_name: pgadmin_container
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
        volumes:
            - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
        ports:
            - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
        restart: unless-stopped

    zookeeper:
        image: debezium/zookeeper:1.3
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
            - 2888:2888
            - 3888:3888
    kafka:
        image: debezium/kafka:1.3
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
        links:
            - zookeeper
        environment:
            - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    postgres:
        image: debezium/example-postgres:1.3
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - PGDATA=/data/postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB:-task_engine}
    connect:
        image: debezium/connect:1.3
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
        links:
            - kafka
            - postgres
        environment:
            - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
            - GROUP_ID=1
            - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
            - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
            - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses

volumes:
    postgres:
    pgadmin:
```

Comment: What does your `plugin.path` property look like? Have you tried putting the JAR containing your custom transform in the same location as the JAR containing `PostgresConnector`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could add the JAR containing your custom transform to the kafka `lib` directory, but that wouldn't be as clean.

Comment: @dnault I have plugin.path=/kafka/connect in my connect-distribted.properties. So there I have debezium-connector-postgres folder also and putted there jar file, but still no luck with this. Tried putting jar into kafka/libs the same situation. Maybe there somekind of a reconfig script should be executed after I put this file in kafka folders? And only after that I should deploy configurations?

Comment: unclear what `com.task.connect.TaskEventRouter` is... Did you add this yourself? Because this does not exist in Debezium, as the error suggests

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, I have created this java class on my local machine and want to use it as an event transformation. It looks like this https://pastebin.com/Ys4yEimb. Then I've created jar file with it and want to use it for transformation on certain stream of events so to say

Comment: @OneCricketeer and the I copied it like this to container docker cp /c/com.task.connect.TaskEventRouter.jar debezium-containder-id:kafka/connect/comtask.connect.TaskEventRouter.jar

Comment: I've created custom docker image with transformation copied and it helped

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712095/using-a-custom-converter-with-kafka-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I made special event transformation java class

From what I can tell, you have not mounted this compiled class into your debezium image or edited the `plugin.path` file to include that JAR

If you have created your own Docker image with that data, then you should change `image: debezium/connect:1.3`

This would explain why the transform is not available